# Cannot install BSDA package into R

Tags: r

I want to use t-test and z-test function, its need to use BSDA package, but
when I install selected, it shows:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.13/BSDA_1.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 833688 bytes (814 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 814 Kb

tar: Failed to set default locale

The downloaded packages are in
    /var/folders/4X/4X093vewHqCEqkPJXgl8I++++TI/-Tmp-//RtmpdKKQ3g/downloaded_packages
```

I don't know why, please help me to tell the mistake. I'm newbie with this program.
Appreciate all answers.

Comment: Please post your `sessionInfo()` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any problem so far. I get a similar message when I install pkg:BSDA from that CRAN repository (although I did not get the message about not setting a default locale.). That message "packages are in
    /var/folders/xS/xSUsVXT..."  is generally a sign of success. My guess is that you are a new user and have not yet understood that in addition to installing packages in the Library, which is a durable event, that you also need to load them into your workspace, which is a temporary event, only persisting as long as your session. Try this:

```
library(BSDA)
```

If Dirk is correct and that local message is a sign of failure, then in the past some people have reported success with this procedure (to be done in a Terminal session) taken from the Mac-R-FAQ:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: But `tar: Failed to set default locale` seems to indicate that opening of the compressed tar archive failed.

Comment: Then why does it report deposition of a package in the temp folder?

Comment: Not sure, that could just be step one of downloading and storing before step 2 (opening of tarball) fails. Also, doesn't `.tgz` imply OS X? I don't use that myself and have few concrete tips to offer.

Comment: Yes. Both the questioner and I are on Macs.